# Скроллинг фрейма

Tags: javascript

Есть фрейм, как узнать на сколько прокручено содержимое фрейма при клике на кнопку?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`iframe` это отдельный объект `window`. Вам нужно сначала попытать получить доступ к `iframe.window.document`, а затем получить значение `scrollTop` элемента `body` в этом `iframe`. Если `src iframe` удовлетворяет `same origin policy` - тогда всё ок, а если iframe с другого домена, тогда ничего не получится.

```
var fr = document.getElementById('iframeID');
var fw = (fr.contentWindow || fr.contentDocument);
if ( !!!fw.document) fw = fw.defaultView;
var IFRAME_SCROLL = fw.document.getElementsByTagName('BODY')[0].scrollTop;
```

Что-то типа этого вот. Ещё нужно учесть `position` элементов.

Comment: то что нужно, спасибо

Answer (score 2):

Если Вы знаете изначальное значение *`height()`*, то можно сравнить:

```
$('#button').click(function(){
  alert('На данный момент height: ' + $('#object').height());
});
```

ну или если Вам это поможет, то `scroll` можно отслеживать вот таким образом:

```
$('#scroll').scroll(function(){
  alert('Был использован scroll');
});
```

Comment: мне нужно на чистом js и именно для iframe

Comment: Чем вам jQuery не угодил в iframe?

Comment: какая разница чем, мне ради этого не нужно подключать эту библиотеку, у меня всё на чистом js